# Как постепенно двигать элемент вдоль строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, есть строка "00000000". Как мне двигать, например, единицу вдоль этой строки таким образом:
10000000
01000000
00100000
00010000
00001000
00001000

и т.д до конца строки

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(0, len(list_)):
    list_[i] = "1"
    print("".join(list_))
    list_[i] = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1** - с использованием срезов и f-строк

```
text = "00000000"
for i, _ in enumerate(text):
    print(f'{text[:i]}1{text[i + 1:]}')
```

**Вариант 2** - с использованием оператора сдвига вправо и f-строк с форматированием вывода двоичного числа

```
start = 2 ** 7
while start > 0:
    print(f'{start:>08b}')
    start >>= 1
```

**Вариант 3** - с использованием умножения строк

```
for i in range(8):
    print(f'{"0"*i}1{"0"*(7-i)}')
```

```
10000000
01000000
00100000
00010000
00001000
00000100
00000010
00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_str = '00000000'
for i in range(0, len(my_str)):
    new_str = my_str[0:i]+'1'+my_str[i+1:]
    print(new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

С использованием степени числа 10:

```
my_str = '0000000'

length = len(my_str)
for x in range(length-1,-1,-1):
    print(f'{10**x:0{length}}')
```